# How grappelli find url?

Tags: django, tinymce, django-grappelli

I write this code block to my admin.py

```
class Media:
    js = [
        settings.STATIC_URL+'grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
        settings.STATIC_URL+'grappelli/tinymce_setup/tinymce_setup.js',
    ]
```

But I dont have grappelli folder under static folder

```
my STATIC_URL ="/static/
```

How works tinymce ?

When I put grappelli folder under the static folder  and modified the tinymce it does not see my modification

Why could it be?

Comment: are you using the django dev server `./manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: Django dev server will automatically serve the static files from your installed apps, but in production you have to run `./manage.py collectstatic` to copy the static files from apps into your `STATIC_ROOT` dir. You shouldn't have to manually copy Grappelli files.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your setup (and whether it's a production or development server), you might need to run..

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

.. to copy all the static files to the correct folder.